# Unable to Add Liquidity from ERC20 Token Contract

Tags: solidity, erc-20, uniswap

I am trying to include the Uniswap addLiquidityEth() function in this simple ERC20 token that I am deploying via Remix. When calling the addLiq() function, I get the rather unhelpful error message `Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted]` which can be viewed here: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x9a46a0e6b4296649042c3105b80d346f94d128d0751dee3acb8d48650e37b182

The inputs I am using for the function are:

- token: (address of deployed contract,
  0xEf9831A8F063fB78747dC4F9C90A0E37b6eb8299)
- amountTokenDesired:
  5000000000000000000 (5 tokens)
- amountTokenMin: 5000000000000000000 (5
  tokens)
- amountEthMin: 100000000000000000 (0.1 tokens)
- deadline: 1622219281 (currently ~20 mins in the future)

I am including 0.1 ether in the attempted transaction, as can be seen on the error page.

The solidity code for the token is:

````
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

interface IUniswap {
    function addLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint amountTokenDesired,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity);

}

interface IERC20 {
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}

contract TestAddLiquidity {

    address internal constant UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;

    IUniswap public uniswap;

    constructor() public {
        uniswap = IUniswap(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS);
    }
    
    function addLiq(address token,
        uint amountTokenDesired,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        uint deadline) external payable {
     
        IERC20(token).approve(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS, amountTokenDesired);
        uniswap.addLiquidityETH{ value: msg.value }(
            token,
            amountTokenDesired,
            amountTokenMin,
            amountETHMin,
            msg.sender,
            deadline
        );

    }
      
}```

What do I need to change in my code to successfully add liquidity through a function in the ERC20 token contract? How could I better troubleshoot this myself?
````

Comment: Have you found a solution?